# MVC - On Select thumbnail, show data from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc

i have a script if the user select a thumbnail shows
 the larger image and the id from my database.

Until this point its works very well

what i try to do now is when the user clicks on the
thumbnail, i want to show the data which are in my table.

how can i do that?

My database relationship:

in my database i have 2 tables which one has the primary key
and the other the foreign key.

when i select the thumbnail which are in the table with the
primary key, i want to show the data from my other table
which contains the foreign key.

**My code:
Javascript:**

```
 function swap(image) {
        document.getElementById("imagem-selec").src = image.href;
        $("input[name='Id_Img']").val($(image).data("id"));
    }
```

**HTML to show the list of thummbnails:**

```
@foreach (var p in ViewBag.Img)
            {           
                <li>
                    <a href="~/Files/@p.Name" onclick="swap(this); return false;" data-id="@p.Id">
                        <img src="~/Files/@p.Name"/>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

**Html which receive the path**

```
 <div id="wrap">         
    <img id="i-selec" src=""/>   
  </div>
```

Any sugestions?

Thanks in advance

UDPATE MY CODE:

**Script**

```
  function swap(image) {
        var imageID = $(image).data("id");

        $.ajax("/{Admin}/GetImageData",
        {
            data: JSON.stringify({ ID: imageID }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // Add your content to DOM here:
                // values in data.data1 etc...
                values in data.De, data.Sc
            }      
            error: function () {
            alert("error!");
            }
         });
    };
```

**Controller:**

```
  public JsonResult GetImageData(int ID)
        {
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter
                (@"SELECT C.* From Content C inner join Image B on C.ID_Img = B.Id WHERE C.Id=" + ID, cn);
                SqlCommandBuilder sqlCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapt);
                DataSet data = new DataSet();
                sqlAdapt.Fill(data, "Content ");

                cn.Close();
                return Json(data);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are two choices:

- Load the data in the view and have it hidden, on page load, and have the click event simply show the data.
- Have an AJAX call to get the data that you want on the click event, and add the data when the call returns.

I would personally go with the AJAX call, as it uses a little extra network overhead on the requests, but potentially saves a lot of useless data from being downloaded:

```
// Data model.
class ImageData
{
    public int data1 { get; set; }
    public string data2 { get; set; }
    ...
}

// Controller action. Data access abstracted out.
public JsonResult GetImageData(int ID)
{
    ImageData data = DataAccess.GetImageData(ID);
    return Json(data);
}
```

Your JavaScript might look something like:

```
function swap(image) {
    var imageID = $(image).data("id");

    $.ajax("/{YourControllerHere}/GetImageData",
    {
        data: JSON.stringify({ ID: imageID }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // creating the element to add
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.setAttribute("id", imageID);
            $(image).parent().append(div);

            //adding the data here. do this for each data item?
            $("#"+imageID).append(data.details.YOUR_PROPERTY_HERE); 
        }      
        error: function () {
            alert("error!");
        }
    });
}
```

The success callback has a parameter named "data". This is a JavaScript object representation of the data you returned in the controller action JsonResult.

Comment: i try to implement your ajax code, but when i insert the controller action i got error on the dataaccess.getimagedata...

Comment: DataAccess.GetImageData() will have to be implemented before calling it. How are you accessing the SQL currently?

Comment: i have a ControllerAction with sqlConnection / sqlCommand
etc... where i do a select from my database to receive 
the data

Comment: Firstly, change the ImageData class to match the data in your database that want to show. Where the DataAccess.GetImageData() is called, use SQL commands to set the data for the "ImageData data" variable, or create the DataAccess class and do it there.

Comment: Looks like it should work, you just need to add the dom elements on the ajax success callback.

Comment: can you show me an example how to add the dom elements pls? im trying to understand what i have to do

Comment: Updated the JavaScript. You may want to refine the HTML that is added, but you get the idea. Do "console.log(data)" in the success function if you want to see the data object in your console.